# How to display Date only in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Here is my problem:

In this picture were I click the report preview, https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj8SUzzqy6-BljoitiMfCWSsA5k2, It shows the correct way that I want to display the date. 
But in running the program
it show this https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aj8SUzzqy6-Bljt-yuybckhLWLiz. It shows the date but it also show 12:00:00 time.

Help how to solve this!

Comment: the question is unclear. and what are those links? onedrive?

Comment: Do you have an example value? to make it like July 18, 2016

Comment: Right click on the date field and select Format. There will be an option for Short Date. Select it.

Comment: short date shows ex. 8/18/2016 I want to show the full name of month. -_-

Answer (score 0):

Open your CR==>Click Field Explorer==> right click Formula Fields==>new==>Formula Name==>Formula Editor then paste this:

```
LOCAL STRINGVAR STR3:=MONTHNAME(TONUMBER('01')) & " " & '01' & ", " & '2016';
```

==>Click save and Close==>Drag Formula name into Section 1 to test==> run project

This is an Example from DB Using Substring(field,1,4)  as YEAR and so on .....something like that:

```
LOCAL STRINGVAR STR3:=MONTHNAME(TONUMBER({Command.CAP_MONTH})) & " " & {Command.CAP_DAY} & ", " & {Command.CAP_YEAR};
```

Comment: but I want it from the date from my database.

Comment: That is Worked perfectly to me, I dont know how you get a record from your DB, it is using ODBC Connection.

Answer (score 0):

Pass you date data in the parameter in crystal report. Then drag it to the field where it belong and customize it.

Or if it's included in the query no need to pass it in the parameter just drag it to the field so that you can customize it.

This are the steps:
Right click your parameter - Format Object - Choose Date tab - select format you want/customize it then click Ok.

That's it. hope this will help you :)